# Cache registery issue in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am having some problem with `cache` registry. Here, how  I configured cache

```
resources.cache.frontEnd = core
resources.cache.backEnd = file
resources.cache.frontEndOptions.lifetime = 1200
resources.cache.frontEndOptions.automatic_serialization = true
resources.cache.backEndOptions.lifetime = 3600
resources.cache.backEndOptions.cache_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../cache"
```

After any page I load I am receiving following error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception'
> with message 'Unable to resolve plugin "cache"; no corresponding
> plugin with that name' in
> C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\hotelrwanda\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:330
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\hotelrwanda\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(382):
> Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->getPluginResource('cache')
>
> #### 1 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\hotelrwanda\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(394):
>
> Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->getPluginResources() #2
> C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\hotelrwanda\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(625):
> Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->getPluginResourceNames()
>
> #### 3 C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\hotelrwanda\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(586):
>
> Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #4
> C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\hotelrwanda\library\Zend\Application.php(355):
> Zend_Applicatio in
> C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\hotelrwanda\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php
> on line 330

I am sure that this is configuration problem. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following line to your config file, before your cache configuration :

```
pluginPaths.App_Application_Resource_ = App/Application/Resource
```

The error message means that Zend Framework cannot find a "cache" plugin.

Comment: What should write for this App_Application_Resource_ becaue I wrote just `pluginPaths.Core_Application_Resource   = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Core/Application/Resource"`

Comment: And it is still giving the same message

Answer (score 0):

It should be `cachemanager` not `cache`. Link to docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.cachemanager

Answer (score 0):

### Error

The error means no "**Cache.php**" file can be found under the configured **pluginPaths**, either under the default directory "/library/Zend/Application/Resource" or the additional paths defined as pluginPaths in your configuration.

### Solution

Most probably the **`pluginPaths`** in your configuration([application.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820528/application-ini-how-it-works)) are not defined correctly or not at all.
So the plugin cannot be found.

I have several `pluginPaths` defined and when I tried to clone the zend app I had to redefine these locations and I made a mistake at one of them which resulted at this error.

### Resource plugins

In Zend 1, [resource plugins](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html) are classes and most are defined in application.ini with their parameters. They are initiated when required by the application.

The default resource plugin path is [/library/Zend/Application/Resource](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/tree/release-1.12.20/library/Zend/Application/Resource), additional plugin paths can be defined using:

```
pluginPaths.Custom_Resource_Path = "path/to/Resource"
```

Custom classes can be added under "path/to/Resource":

```
// path/to/Resource/Custom.php:
class Path_To_Resource_Custom extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract 
{
      public function setParam1($param1) {
          ...
      }
      public function init()
      {
          ...
      }
```

In application.ini, the configuration is added:

```
resources.custom.param1 = '...';
resources.custom.param2 = '...';
```

Also

- by creating a class with the same name as a default resource in the above directory, e.g. Log.php, the default resource can be overridden.
- default resources can be changed, e.g. resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"