# application.ini - How it works

Tags: zend-framework

I'm just start to learning Zend Framework 1.12.9. and I can't understand how to work application.ini file. So, to my question was more understandable, I will give an example:

```
`; application/configs/application.ini

[production]
; PHP settings we want to initialize
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"

    resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
    resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
    resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"


[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1`
```

So, this is standart example then you start learning Zend. So I can't understand syntax of this file and how is routing do.

```
`resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"`
```

That means this lines? Mybe someone can give some link to good totorial please... I will appreciate it. 
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find tutorial about these particular config params at http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html

If you've never had any experience with ZF1, go ahead and read the introduction http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

FYI, the first version is an old one. Perhaps you should consider using ZF2.